# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I run `php artisan route:list` but get this error

**In AbstractGateway.php line 338:**

```
Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

what does it mean?

I am using laravel5.5 running on WSL with ubuntu18.04 and installed php7.3

tried this also

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

but got this,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-curl : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I am stack, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Could run `apt-get update && apt-cache search curl | grep php` and check which one package available in your repository.

Comment: Thanks for help man